# Class polymorphism equivalent in R language

Tags: r, polymorphism

In C++, we can do some class polymorphism like that:
(thanks to https://www.quora.com/What-is-polymorphism-in-C++-1)

```
struct Animal{
   virtual void speak() const = 0;
};

void doSpeak(const Animal &animal){
   animal.speak();
}

struct Cat : public Animal{
   void speak() const override{
      std::cout << "Miau" << '\n';
   }
}

struct Dog : public Animal{
   void speak() const override{
      std::cout << "Bau" << '\n';
   }
}

int main(){
   Cat murka;
   Dog rex;

   doSpeak(murka);
   doSpeak(rex);
}
```

Now, admit that the class `Animal` is replaced by `data.frame`, the class `Cat` by `my.data.frame`, and the method `speak` which I want to override is replaced by the data.frame operator `[`.

What is the correct way to do that under the language R?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: Sorry for the long post. As requested, below is what I would need regarding my customized class `my.data.frame`. I use C++ vocabulary (my native language ^^) because I'm not an expert in R.

1. `my.data.frame` can be constructed from a real `data.frame`:

```
mtcars
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# ...

class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
mdf = my.data.frame(mtcars) # Don't know yet how to do that
class(mdf)
# [1] "my.data.frame"
```

2. `my.data.frame` inherits from `data.frame` so that I can manipulate any instance of `my.data.frame` exactly as if it was a `data.frame`:

```
names(mdf)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
mdf = mdf[,-9]                          # Remove "am" column
names(mdf)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "gear" "carb"
merc = rep(0, nrow(mdf))                # Initialize vector of 'Merc flags'
merc[grep("Merc", row.names(mdf))] = 1  # Set to 1 the flag for each 'Merc' car
mdf = cbind(mdf, merc)                  # Add 'Merc flags' as a new variable
names(mdf)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "gear" "carb" "merc"
```

3. `my.data.frame` contains some additionnal attributes (ex: a `roles` attribute to store the role of each variable):

```
attr(mdf, "roles") <- rep("na", ncol(mdf))  # Create roles attribute
attr(mdf, "roles")[1] <- "main"             # Use the 'Miles per Gallon' (mpg) variable as *main* variable
attr(mdf, "roles")[ncol(mdf)] <- "filt"     # Use the 'Merc flags' vector as a *filter*
attr(mdf, "roles")
# [1] "main" "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "filt"
```

4. I currently develop some R functions that use `my.data.frame` and its additionnal attributes:

```
# Return the maximum of the main variable within filtered samples
my.max <- function(mdf) {
  midx = grep("main", attr(mdf,"roles"))
  if (length(midx) == 0)
    stop("No main variable defined")
  fidx = grep("filt", attr(mdf,"roles"))
  if (length(fidx) == 0)
    return (max(mdf[,midx]))
  else
    return (max(mdf[mdf[fidx]==1,midx]))
}
my.max(mdf) # Get the maximum MPG for Merc cars
# [1] 24.4
```

5. I can copy `my.data.frame` without losing additionnal attributes:

```
mdf2 = mdf           # Simple copy works
attr(mdf2, "roles")  # Attribute kept => OK
# [1] "main" "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "filt"
mdf2 = mdf[-1,]      # Copy removing first line
attr(mdf2, "roles")  # Attribute kept => OK
# [1] "main" "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "filt"
mdf2 = mdf[,-8]      # Copy removing "vs" column
attr(mdf2, "roles")  # Attribute lost => NOK...   but WHY ???
# NULL
```

6- *At any time*, the additional information of `my.data.frame` must be consistent with the `data.frame` structure (number of variables):

```
mdf = mdf[,-11]     # Remove last variable (with role 'filt')
attr(mdf, "roles")  # Admitting that roles attribute is kept, I would need the following behavior:
# [1] "main" "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"   "na"
my.max(mdf) # Get the maximum MPG for ALL cars
# [1] 33.9
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you show some of your attempts to replicate the function?

Comment: I think this is pretty common. Consider your `Animal` to be `data.frame`, your `Cat` to be `tbl` from the `tibble` package, and your `speak` to be `print`. Basically, add `my.data.frame` to the class vector, `x = data.frame()`, `class(x) = c("my.data.frame", class(x))`, and then define your own `[.my.data.frame` function.

Comment: @NelsonGon I do not know yet which technic (S3, S4 or Reference Classes) I have to use to inherits from data.frame. In the class my.data.frame, I want to store some additionnal information which must be updated each time the number of lines or columns is modified.
I want to transmit an instance of my.data.frame to all R functions which know only standard data.frame while ensuring the consistency of my additionnal information.

Comment: Overriding `[` may be a bit more complicated, but I think the `tibble` package   example is still a good one. Without having more details of what you're aiming for in R, I don't know how to make a better answer.

Comment: @Gregor I have edited the inital post with details. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is gonna be tough. At it's simplest, you could start with `my.data.frame = function(x) {
  if (! inherits(x, "data.frame")) stop("x must be a data frame");
  class(x) = c("my.data.frame", class(x));
  return(x)
}`. It works, as you show, up to the `mdf[-8]` part. To solve that, you may need to implement `[.my.data.frame` to keep the attributes around in the general case. [This blog post reimplements `[` in C++ and handles attributes](http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/01/24/understanding-data-frame-subsetting/), so that should be helpful...

Comment: You can further modify `[` to keep the attributes in sync with the columns. (But you may also need a version of `[[`). You might also want to look at `Hmisc::labels`. I'm not sure if it works any better, but it's somewhat similar. They make the labels attributes *of each column* rather than of the entire data frame, which might save you quite a bit of work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand that I need to reimplement (copy) the `[.data.frame` function.
I was expecting extending `data.frame` class (inherit from) and overriding the `[` operator by calling firstly the base class operator, secondly synchronizing the `my.data.frame` class attributes.
I have tried S3, S4 and RC class system but with no success. I am maybe too much influenced by C++...

Comment: I am stuck in the same hell man, my colleagues are using R and I've been frantically searching for the equivalent of self, def, init, all those goodies that we give for granted in normal languages.
I can not fathom how any of you can write more than 100 lines in R without getting totally lost.